# Как создать интерактивный план здания c Dash и Plotly?

Tags: python, svg, pandas, plotly, dash

При создании интерактивного дашборда с помощью Python, Dash и Plotly, требуеться создать интерактивное окно, на подобе этого: https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-layers/, только вместо карты должно быть SVG изображение с планом помещения: [Floor_plan](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wbQ_k0Rkr4xVWRlpgHZeq3h6Qqt0Cm8X/view?usp=sharing). У каждого полигона на изображении есть свой ID. Данное окно которое можно будет увеличить должно быть связанно с ID-фильтром при помощи которого можно будет выбрать те или иные помещения.

При помощи каких библиотек можно это сделать?

Всё что я нашел на эту тему это следующие статьи:

- https://plotly.com/python/datashader/
- https://plotly.com/python/imshow/

Comment: отправил вам запрос на разрешение скачивания файла Floor_plan. с Google диска

Comment: Доступ предоставил

Comment: скачал файл, просто жуть 11Мб И это не svg, а растровое изображение сконвертированное в формат `data:image/jpeg;base64` поэтому это всё равно картинка, у которой естественно нет никаких id полигонов.

Comment: загрузил новый фаил, пройдите ещё раз по ссылке Floor_Plan

Comment: Ну вот это совсем другое дело. файл 46 Кб и id есть и подсказки выводятся. После оптимизации можно будет в несколько раз уменьшить

Comment: нашел кое что еще на эту тему: https://plotly.com/python/images/ но как связать информацию из таблицы с формами в SVG?

Comment: определять по `id="23.21.01.027"` cпомощью `23.21.01.027.getBBox()` координаты X,Y width, htight и подставлять их во `viewBox="$(X) $(Y) $(width) $(height)"` тогда выведется на весь экран нужный полигон. Правда имена `id` не подходящие,- идут через точку, их надо переименовать, так как в c 'этим видом `ID`, предложенное мной решение не подойдет

Comment: Это позволит выбрать только один полигон. Моей целью являеться загрузить в дашборд SVG изображения, связать их с данными из таблицы и с помощью кода настроить интерактивный фильтр. Допустим когда я фильтром выберу определенный тип помещений они должны выделиться красным в окне плана. У каждого помещения (полигона) есть свой перечень характеристик в таблице.

Comment: идея конечно заманчивая, но как можно одновременно увеличить несколько однотипных помещений, если они разбросаны по разным местам, остается только подкрасить однотипные помещения при наведении на одно из них

Comment: На странице https://plotly.com/python/images/ в рубрике "Annotating layout image with shapes" есть начало того что надо. Увеличить можно при помощи встроеного в окне зума, вопрос в том как связать полигоны из SVG, c данными из таблицы и менять цвет полигона при нужном филтре?